# How can I return the value of a field in C# if I want to execute a function on that field?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a model that looks like this:

```
    [DisplayName("Subject")]
    public string SubjectID { get; set; }

    public string SubjectText ??
```

What I want to do is to have the value of SubjectText be equal to the following when a user requests it:

```
SubjectText = SubjectReference.GetSubjectText(Model.PageMeta.SubjectID)
```

I also don't want anyone to be able to set this value. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a property:

```
public string SubjectText {
    get {
         return SubjectReference.GetSubjectText(Model.PageMeta.SubjectID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
public string SubjectText { 
    get { return SubjectReference.GetSubjectText(Model.PageMeta.SubjectID); }
}
```

edit: ninja'd

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
public string SubjectID { get; set; }

public string SubjectText
{
    get
    { 
        return "anything you want here"; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [property getter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx) that references the other property, `SubjectID`, like this:

```
public string SubjectText { get { SubjectReference.GetSubjectText(SubjectID) } }
```

This will be a read-only property because it doesn't have a setter.